# Shows "your device isn't compatible with this version" for my paid app on Nexus 7

Tags: android, google-play

I have two apps (free & paid) that are exactly same except for ad showing and not showing.
I bought Nexus 7 and tried to download my apps on Google Play, it allows for free version but paid version shows: "your device isn't compatible with this version".

Manifest file is exactly same for both:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, after one or two days, it appears to the market again. I didn't have to do anything.

(Weird)

Answer (score 5):

Check your permissions. If you're using something like the camera, you need to say that it's not required, and then make sure your code checks for it. I had to add the following "uses-feature" line to my manifest to get my app to work.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

I then used the following code to set a flag, so that I wouldn't call anything in the app that tried to use the camera.

```
PackageManager pm = this.getContext().getPackageManager();
Boolean hasFlashSupport = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into similar issue with my app. Following change helped.

```
<compatible-screens>
....
    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Look at answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745425/348154 and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34076

Answer (score 2):

Does setting 'Copy protection' to 'Off' change anything?. Jelly Bean has a new copy protection (forward locking) scheme which is incompatible with the old one and automatically on for paid apps.