# Delphi XE7 Application on Galaxy P5200

Tags: delphi, galaxy-tab, delphi-xe7

I downloaded the trial version of Delphi XE7.

After successfully compiling and running some demos on a a virtual device, I connected a 
Galaxy Tab 3 P5200 through the USB cable.

When I compile and run an application, it is correctly deployed to the device, but when it starts a black screen appears with the following message:

*Application does not support this device*

Comment: A search here for `[android] Galaxy` turns up http://stackoverflow.com/q/23625720 (which also shows up in the link of related posts to the right). Also, have you verified that your device meets all of the requirements (particularly those of the GPU and OS versions) as described [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development)?

Comment: @KenWhite: thanks, but I already found the (negative) answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Delphi XE7 datasheet](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/datasheet) there is a small box with the "Supported Deployment Platforms" ... for Android they say that an ARMv7 device with NEON support is required. The Galaxy 3 P5200 has an Intel Atom CPU Z2560 ... so Delphi XE7 simply cannot build applications for this device ...

Comment: On the [current roadmap](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43677), support for Intel CPUs on Android devices is scheduled for "after 2014".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem but I'll answer it anyways since this problem might occur to other people as it happened with me.

I was able to solve this issue following this:
[Running Delphi Applications on Android Intel](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-october-running-android-intel.html)

From what I could understand, Firemonkey tries to inject code into the application as a some sort of test, and by doing so it uses both mips and x86 architecture, and those are not supported by Intel Atom processors...

Galaxy Tab 3 uses an Intel processor, so I'm sure this will work for you.

In the IDE, open the Deployment Manager (**Project > Deployment**), and locate the following entry:

[image]
After doing so, clean and re-build your project, the application should work just fine.

You can read more about it on [Embarcadero's Wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Running_Your_Android_Application_on_an_Android_Device).