# Why my App is not compatible with nexus 7 in Google Play?

Tags: android, manifest, tablet

I just released my app for phones and tablets but it is not showing up in Google Play for tablets.

Checked on Nexus 7 and Asus eeeePad

This is what I have in my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="bluey.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: it seems correct... you can see what features requires your app in android market console. What's your app name?

Comment: tvdpi is messy and might not be included in android:anyDensity="true"

Comment: Bluey....[link] (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bluey.com&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImJsdWV5LmNvbSJd)

Comment: this is the function required:android.hardware.location.gps
android.hardware.location.network
android.hardware.screen.portrait
android.hardware.touchscreen
android.hardware.wifi

Comment: someone copied my question. I originally posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play

Answer (score 16):

Hopefully the answer it is not too late. Have a look at your permissions and bear in mind that Nexus 7 has
-No telephony
-A single front facing camera (apps requiring the android.hardware.camera feature will not be available on Nexus 7)
 Always declare hardware features that aren't critical to your app as required="false"
In your permissions list are asking for
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`
that's why your app is not compatible with Nexus 7
if calling is not essential for your app to run just declare in your manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: The above feature is already added by OP in manifest file as is indicated in question.