# Can't install my first app on Play. Galaxy Nexus between Supported Devices, but apparently not my Nexus

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-permissions

I just uploaded my first app to market and it shows a whopping 1198 devices as supported. Devices, such as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/afQxC.png

But when I try to install it on my phone, it does not seem to work:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQTKM.png

This is of course my developer phone, so it makes no sense. Android 4.2.2, build JDQ39.

Can you please take a look and point out something obvious I missed? Pretty please?

My manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="se.krizan.knihajazd"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="0.2.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>

<!-- small size screens -->
 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<!--Only hdpi and xhdpi for normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<!-- all large size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<!-- all xlarge size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>


<permission
    android:name="se.my.application.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="se.my.application.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />
```

Comment: Strange, it says that its not compatible with my Nexus 7, which is 4.2.2 also.  Do you need to have `<compatible-screens>` and `supports-screens` in your manifest?  I published a location based app for an Android course I took and my manifest did not contain those values.

Comment: Check out question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play which explains why the app doesn't show up for my Nexus 7.  Perhaps this is the same issue with your developer phone, perhaps your phone's DPI isn't any of the ones you have listed.  Again, do you really need to specify all this?

Comment: Strange, your app can be installed on my Galaxy Nexus. Is there any particular reason why you want to specify supported DPI for each screen size? If your app in fact works for all DPI in all screen size, then those specification can be removed. As it stands now, you are specifying that your app does NOT support tvdpi (Nexus 7) and xxhdpi (HTC Butterfly, HTC ONE, Galaxy S4, and practically all future Android flagship phones).

Answer (score 0):

Alright folks, I found the reason for this.

I uninstalled the developer signed version of my app from my phone, went to bed and woke up to my app being now compatible with my phone. I think the developer signature was the problem.

It works now! Thanks!