# Why my app is not compatible with some devices?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I don't understand why my app is not compatible with many devices, in fact 479, between them Nexus 7, Samsung Galaxy III, Xtouch X405... I have tried many configurations in the manifest file but I couldn't get more compatibles mobiles.

My actual configuration is:

```
    <supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

And in Google Play: http://d.pr/i/jpEB

I think that with this configuration I am supporting all screens with any configuration and only restriction of hardware is the camera. I read this post: [Why my App is not showing up on tablets in Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play) about a similar problem and I have tried to use the tag  with all screenDensity even 213 and 480 but I got less compatible devices than with my actual configuration.

Anyone knows what is it the problem in my configuration?

Thank you,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try using one more thing in manifest which is for compatible screens:**

```
<compatible-screens

<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi">
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi">

</compatible-screens>
```

Like above you can keep adding different combinations which your app is going to support.

Comment: I have tried with all possible combinations, even for the screen density 213 and 480, and I haven't increased the compatible devices in fact I have less that with the configuration that I related in my question