# Google Play doesn't offer app for installation on Nexus 7. How change Android Manifest?

Tags: android, manifest, nexus-7

I have published an application on Google Play. All is ok when I install on my Galaxy S3 or any other phone. But when I want to install this app on my Nexus 7, I can't find it on Google Play.

Here is my manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="XX.XX.XX"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                       android:smallScreens="true"
                       android:anyDensity="true"
                       android:xlargeScreens="true"
                       android:normalScreens="true"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name="splash"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:name="XX.XX.XX.MainActivity">

        </activity>
                <activity android:name="vocation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></activity>
        <activity android:name="XX" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></activity>
        <activity android:name="XX" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></activity>
        <activity android:name="XXX" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></activity>


</application>
```

Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11745425/1434631

Comment: @Nermeen: This manifest does not have a `<compatible-screens>` element in it.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the version you have in the Play Store has `android:required="false"` on your `CALL_PHONE` permission?

Answer (score 3):

update the [uses-permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

add [uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the following permission prevents if from being available for the Nexus 7:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"></uses-permission>
```

The Nexus 7 doesn't have phone capabilities and so it won't be supported. The android:required attribute isn't needed by the way and doesn't do anything (it's ignored by Android).

Comment: I just try to remove "android:required="false"

Comment: As I said android:required="false" doesn't do anything and removing it won't resolve your issue. It's the permission itself. If your app needs to make phone calls then it won't run on a Nexus 7 because that device can't make phone calls and so it won't be available to this device in Google Play. If your app doesn't need to make phone calls remove the permission completely and it will be available to Nexus 7 devices too.

Answer (score -1):

you must use `compatible-screens` tag and not `supports-screens`

Comment: And your proof of this is... what, exactly? Bear in mind that the OP wants the app available on devices of *all screen sizes and densities*, given the existing setup. Moreover, `<supports-screens>` is not a filter on the Play Store, except for *smaller* screens (e.g., saying you do not support `-small` screens will filter you out of the market for such devices).