# Compatibility Issues with Nexus 10

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-compatibility

No matter what I do I cannot get my application to be considered compatible with my nexus 10. On the play store, I believe the issue is in my manifest file, but I'm not seeing where the problem is. Any advice?

What I've seen:
[Why my App is not showing up on tablets in Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play)
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tv.lifechurch.lifegroupsjb"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <supports-screens 
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all large large screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:name=".FindALifeGroup"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".LGSettings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="tv.lifechurch.LGSettings" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play

Comment: It would but the solution only works for the nexus 7, I forgot to mention that.. @EugenMartynov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And one line of code fixed it all!

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Plus one for answering your own question.