# I can't enable first gen nexus 7 in the play store

Tags: android, nexus-7

I am having issues getting the first gen nexus 7 to show up in the play store. I have tried several different configs. The following is the relevant part of my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus 7 2012 has a screen density of tvdpi, which means you're going to have to support tvdpi.

> The Nexus 7 has an interesting screen:
>
> - 7 inches.
> - 800x1280.
> - "tvdpi" density (numerically that is 213).
> - 600 x 961 in dp units.

Try:

```
<screen android:screenSize="large or normal, not 100% sure" android:screenDensity="tvdpi" />
```

https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8

**EDIT:**
Found this similar SO question. [Why my App is not showing up on tablets in Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play?rq=1)