# Android App is not showing for tablet users of Google play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, samsung-mobile

My android app is not found through tablets in google play store.
the App manifest is as :

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"  android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

I have tested the apk on my tablet its working fine. But when i published my app on google play, i wasnt able to see my app on my tablet from google play?
Kindly Help!!
thanx in advance...

Comment: you probably dont have the layout-large-mdpi folder ??

Comment: check this too [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: It looks like your app is making use of the camera, not all tablet have a camera so it may be worth setting it to not require a camera

Comment: i have added another feature to the manifest will it work??   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"  android:required="false" />

Comment: @Ishan_Deb, did u solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

please add following line. It should solve your problem !!

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are only two ways your APP will not show up on playstore

1. OS version is less than minsdk version supported by app. I don't think this is the issue for you as you are using minsdk as 8.
2. Device needs some feature that tablet does not support. This will most likely be the culprit.

Before jumping to conclusions your best option is to browse that app from browser. Here you can see if the app is compatible with list of your devices. Here you would see reason as to why your app is not compatible. Attaching a screenshot from similar issue I faced -

[image]

For me it looks like phones not having GPS dont have access to this app.  You could try

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```