# App not shown in Play-Store for Nexus 7 After SMS Permission added

Tags: android, android-manifest, nexus-7

My published android app was being shown in search result of play-store in Nexus 7.
But ever since I added the SMS receive & read permissions to the app & uploaded the new version, I can't see it in the search result from any Nexus 7(don't having SIM card support) but being able to build in Nexus 7 device from Android-Studio.

I haven't explicitly set the screen-compatibility in manifest & the older version of the app was OK in Nexus 7. So can't I assume [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play) isn't suitable for me?

The permission & feature requirement list in my app-manifest is like the below:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

I don't have the luxury to upload any new version & test for it in a trial & error basis, but have to get a fast solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't see your app because it uses Google Play recognized that your device does not have the necessary features to run it. Follow @Mattia's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

> If an application requests hardware-related permissions, Google Play
>   assumes that the application uses the underlying hardware features and
>   therefore requires those features, even though there might be no
>   corresponding to  declarations. For such permissions,
>   Google Play adds the underlying hardware features to the metadata that
>   it stores for the application and sets up filters for them.
>
> For example, if an application requests the CAMERA permission but does
>   not declare a  element for android.hardware.camera,
>   Google Play considers that the application requires a camera and
>   should not be shown to users whose devices do not offer a camera.
>
> If you don't want Google Play to filter based on a specific implied
>   feature, you can disable that behavior. To do so, declare the feature
>   explicitly in a  element and include an
>   android:required="false" attribute. For example, to disable filtering
>   derived from the CAMERA permission, you would declare the feature as
>   shown below.
>
> ```
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
> ```

You can find more information here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Comment: if this is the issue, then why did play-store show & allow the app to install for the previous versions? Is the explanation like - SMS permission by-default requires the telephony feature?

Comment: I just updated my answer with a quote from developer.android.com. For more information visit the URL in the answer

Comment: Seems legit cause ! I'm gonna accept the answer when the uploaded new version will get available in Nexus 7. Btw, thanks :)