# App is not listed in Playstore in google pixel

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-screen-support

I have seen similar questions and tried with those solutions as well but still my issue is not solved so asking this question.

I have an app in playstore I can see that app listed in different devices I have checked in NEXUS 9, NEXUS 7, MOTO G4 etc devices.

But I can't see my app listed in Playstore of Google pixel.

My manifest has the following entries as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play) and some other threads.

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <compatible-screens>

        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />

        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />

        <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="213"
            android:screenSize="large" />

        <!-- For xxhdpi devices we can use 480 as an int value -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        `

        <!-- XXXHdpi Screen -->

        <screen
            android:screenDensity="560"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="560"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="560"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="640"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="640"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="640"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Does anyone faced the similar issue and have solution please suggest me a solution

Regards

Comment: Were you able to figure out @ImGenie ?

Answer (score -1):

Based from this [support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113411?hl=en), if an app or game doesn't appear in your search results, it's possible the item isn't available in your country or compatible with your device. Developers can limit their apps or games to select countries, devices, and service providers. You may also check this [related thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-I-find-the-app-when-searching-by-its-name-in-Google-Play-Store-though-it-is-listed).

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you need to add separate records for 420 density to cover Pixel.